# Ionic 2 ionViewCanLeave hook on pop ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to intercept the back navigation for a page and do some validation before i allow it to go back or not,
also i had a button on the same page the push another page on it, now when i use the  ion View Can Leave  hook it will be fired for both the navigation pop and push, is there anyway that i can do my validation only on the page is popped from the stack?

```js
  ionViewCanLeave(): boolean {
    //here we can either return true or false
    //depending on if we want to leave this view

    if (this.isDirty) {
      this.showConfirm();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```